# Where do I look for learning how to write bare-metal ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm, hardware, bare-metal

I have a small XScale/ARMv5-based device here and despite ARM being a popular architecture, I can't find tutorials or anything simple on ARM assembly that isn't based around an intermediate OS. For instance, there are some X86 "Hello World" tutorials out there showing where to store strings and how to interrupt the CPU to refresh the screen, but I can't find anything similar for ARM.

Where can I find info related to programming a bare-metal ARM processor(-based system)? I'd like to write a simple "Hello World" program to start out with, but I have no clue how to proceed.

Comment: really isnt bare metal x86 asm if you are making system calls.

Comment: That's my mistake then. What I was implying is the idea of writing a program and having it run on a clean memory slate like a bootloader.

Comment: It's the wrong system, but IMO [this tutorial](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/) does a good job of explaining the fundamentals.

Comment: github.com/dwelch67 I have a lot of arm based bare metal code blinks leds and sends stuff out the uart.  look at the raspberry pi one first then maybe mbed or some of the others.

Comment: @dwelch Thanks, but how did you learn all this? Did you read through the architecture manual?

Comment: I have read through the architecture manual, I have written disassemblers soley for the purpose of learning the instruction set, which also means I have to get the assembler to generate that machine code which teaches you how to get the assembler to do things.  I have spent a lot of time compiling and disassembling to see what the compiler and/or linker is doing.

Comment: My day job includes a lot of this work, board bring up and at times chip bring up and yes we use an arm.  But I learned most of this on things like the gameboy advance and various microcontroller boards.  When you get into chip debugging you have to figure out is it a code problem, a chip problem or a board problem (or a sim problem, etc) and that means disassemble and watch the data busses and compare data and instructions to what is supposed to be going by.

Comment: so you have to get very comfortable with the tools, disassembling, machine code, etc.  Ideally get comfortable with trying to get the compiler to generate different code sequences or play with various things so you dont have to everything in assembly...

Comment: the tools (compilers) are constantly evolving so you have to also try to keep up with that.

Comment: xscale adds greatly to the nightmare because they want to be big endian which is not a native arm thing and it is harder to get the tools to build properly so that they make big endian code vs little, etc.  You should be able to put the xscale in little endian mode and then save a lot of headaches with tools, you would be going with the grain for the arm world but against the grain for xscale

Comment: also understand arm has two big endian modes that are incompatible but fortunately so far chips only do one or the other.  One is word invariant (Be32) and byte invariant (be8), you have word invariant, word instructions dont flip in any mode but in word invariant words dont change between big and little, but bytes swap, for byte invariant, bytes dont move between modes but words swap their bytes

Comment: halfwords always swap in both modes

Comment: @dwelch Wow that all sounds like a huge learning curve, but thanks a lot for the detailed answer. Do you think that becoming familiar with the ARM instruction set and eventually reading the architecture/developers manual, would help with learning bare-metal programming to eventually write bootloaders and kernels? I especially have an issue with understanding how to access peripherals like the screen and audio processors.

Comment: not at all you can catch up on basic bare metal stuff in short order, just look at my stuff or the baking pi tutorial for the pi, etc.  you dont need to use asm to do bare metal.  Just look at the manuals for the peripherals.  a few lines of code to turn an led on and off and go from there

Comment: thats what all my repos are for for handholding through those basic steps, once you have an led blinking or whatever you have a foundation to work from just add more register reads and writes to talk to more peripherals.

Comment: @dwelch I understand that I don't NEED assembly, but it's the most raw (humanly understandable) form of programming, and that's what I'm interested in. I will get more familiar with ARM assembly first and then look through your tutorials/code examples. I have another arm-based device, not the pi, but I hope the examples will still help me. Thanks a lot for informing me.

Comment: forgot this was an assembly question when I wrote that.  you can bang out the bulk of a disassembler in an evening and get a stronger handle on the instruction set.  or write or at least use an instruction set simulator, gdb has or can use what was the armulator, I wrote a thumb one lots of visibility to what is going on.  If you write one you can also get a strong handle on the instruction set in an evening.  simulator or disassembler and you can quickly learn the instruction set better than most of the folks out there just writing asm.

Comment: in my raspberry pi repo I have some ramblings in the bare metal and databss directories that may (or may not) help getting a handle on the gnu toolchain, linking in particular can be a pain and a primary source of failure making binaries that actually work. properly written asm will still fail if not linked right

Comment: @dwelch As someone who is new to assembly and low-level stuff in general, it seems like a better idea to just stick to writing it rather than writing a disassembler. I understand that writing such a thing can help my ARM assembly a lot, but it's not something I'd be able to write in one night, especially because ARM CPUs aren't that simple to me. Thanks for the advice, but I'll stick with simplicity for now until I understand the big picture a bit better.

Comment: Voting to close as off topic.

Answer (score 5):

ARM machines do not have a standard bare metal IO interface.  Without a driver that can output the text to some sort of output device (whether it be a serial port or a graphical display), hello world is meaningless.

Your chip or board vendor may have provided you with code for doing this.  If not, you will need to find a driver or implement it yourself.

Comment: The device already runs a stock linux-based OS so I'm sure there's something working in there. How do I find more info about this?

Comment: I'd head to the reference manuals for the specific ARM SoC you have.

Comment: @ZimZim: When a device is running Linux you cannot do "bare metal" I/O but you have to use Linux system calls. You won't find any information on how Linux is doing some I/O on "ARM chips" because this is done in a different way on different ARM chips.

Comment: Bear in mind this may not be as complicated as it sounds - the bare-metal "driver" I wrote for printing hex strings to the UART on an Exynos5 was only about 25 lines of assembly.

Comment: @MartinRosenau I know, I'm not planning to program on that kernel, I want to write something that boots when the device is started (another bootloader/kernel that simply displays a few letters).

Comment: @Notlikethat That might be helpful. How did you understand what this UART does and where did you get all the programming info (aside from looking at the instruction set)?

Comment: @ZimZim: Still you have the problem with the different architectures: On all PC-compatible machines the "bare-metal" programming is the same. So the VGA card is located at address 0xA0000 and 0xB8000 for example. Therefore you will find a lot of x86-based tutorials. (It is of course possible to build a non-PC-compatible machine with an x86 processor - which eventually has been done in the 1980s.) There is no standard architecture for ARM-based computers. So two ARM-based computers may behave totally different. You would need a "Hello world" for your SPECIFIC chip, not for ARM in general.

Comment: @MartinRosenau I was wondering where I could find information on how to access various functions on the CPU and other peripherals, but I already expected that different ARM systems would have different calls. I hope that reading the architecture/developers manual for the device in question will do the trick, in addition to some ARM assembly practice of course.

Comment: @ZimZim The Technical Reference Manual for your SoC/board should say where the configuration registers, etc., for the peripherals are mapped, and how to communicate with them. With a bit of luck the bootloader may have already set up some stuff like a UART (serial port) that you can use straight away.

Comment: Well then, a 1000+ pages, here I come! I'm actually hoping the bootloader hasn't done anything like that, because I'd like to start from scratch (as long as I don't have to touch the physical device from the inside). Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Usually bare-metal programming hardware drivers for an ARM (or any other microcontroller) involves heavy digging into the part's tech reference manual and datasheet. You will likely setup your IDE on one screen and the manual on the other to look up the register descriptions.

You need to know..

- what registers you need to modify to achieve the intended behavior
- the address of that register
- the organisation of that register (what are the meanings of the individual bits?)

Then you can..

- figure out what value the register needs to be set with
- write the value to the register (e.g. by declaring a pointer to it and writing to that pointer)

Be careful with debugging! Sometimes reading a status register will be required to continue or acknowledge steps of the process. Having such a register in the watch of your debugger reads it on a regular basis and can sometimes cause your drivers to only work inside the debugger, but not without it. (A good example for this is the I²C peripherals on the STM32 series.)

*Edit: To answer the original question -
one would probably start looking at the peripheral description of the controller's UART, find out how to set it up, set up the corresponding GPIOs and writing the string "Hello World" to the UART's data register char by char. For most controllers this also requires configuration of the main system clock (and PLLs) and activating the slave clocks for the UART and other peripherals.*